# Desktop start menu shut down button not working

Tags: windows-7

It is pretty weird that when I click 'shut down' button, in start menu, in my desktop computer having windows-7 x32 os installed, to shut it down it does nothing...I have to click the 'shut down' button twice to shut down the pc.
Any having this 'weird' problem?
Thanks.

Comment: try to  check it in safe mode.

Comment: Don't trust any source for Windows 8.1 media except [Microsoft](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/create-reset-refresh-media) itself

Comment: @Ramhound ??? OP is using Windows 7 and in any case what is the connection between his issue and an untrusted source?

Comment: For system doesn't getting shutdown in the pressing the shutdown first.Once you click the shutdown button,it would send close all to the application which is in use but it is not responding to the call.Since you are facing the issue all the times,we request you to check the application running in the system tray.The best solution is do windows update which would resolve the issue